# Facebook iOS SDK 3.1 from Github missing FacebookSDK.framework

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6

I want to use Facebook SDK on XCode 4.5 for integration with iOS6.

I read this [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/). I was using [this .dmg package](https://github.com/downloads/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/FacebookSDK-3.1.pkg) to install the library but I need to track and read the implementation of some methods, so I noticed that there is a repo on [Github](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) with the current source code.

My problem is that I don't know how to install this properly as with the package .dmg. Any ideas on how to do it? I tried to just import the src folder and reference the whole project but I'm having a lot of issues, warnings and errors.

**Update**

I had to do this again, so now I made it work. Here is what I did:

I tried both ways, building the source code (1) and importing the files directly(2). On the first scenario it was easy, on the root folder of Github repo just run:

```
sudo scripts/build_framework.sh
```

You will get the files needed, the same that you get when installing with .pkg. But I needed to track the functions, so I tried to importing the files.

First I added the src folders from the Github repo on my project. I had an issue with duplicated definitions on every file. The problem was on my *Build Settings (BS)*, I was still referencing to the .pkg install directory of Facebook so I had the files duplicated. I removed every reference to that folder on *BS* and then added the files.

After that, on the files that imported the Facebook files I got:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386
```

When I copied the files to XCode, the .m files where not automatically added to the Build Phases / Compile Sources. I added them manually and imported FBConnect.h on my files.

Hope it helps some one with the same issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you include the FacebookSDK via git, you will need to build the framework. Run the following command from within the FacebookSDK directory:

```
scripts/build_framework.sh
```

Then, FacebookSDK.framework will appear in FacebookSDK/build

Comment: mmm I tried that, but I had some errors on build. I needed to keep developing so I'm using just the pkg lib and Its working fine.

Comment: The build script gave you errors? Did you install your command-line utilities through xCode? Would be curious to know what errors you got.

Comment: I had link errors until I linked to the frameworks: account, social and adsupport.

Comment: I just tried now and it worked. I don't remember my other errors but now I had to use sudo to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Add the entire src folder to your project. Import FBConnect.h in any class where you want to use Facebook. The connect class imports the rest of the necessary classes.

```
#import "FBConnect.h"
```

Comment: I was doing that but I had build errors. I just decided to use the .pkg.

Comment: Did you tell the compiler to not apply ARC to the Facebook files? Under Build Phases > Compile Sources, select each of the Facebook SDK .m files, press enter, then add -fno-objc-arc to each of the files.